# React-router how to load component based on props?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

First my routes:

```
const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={authWrapper(App)}>
    <IndexRoute getComponent={resolveIndexComponent} />
    <Route path="about" getComponent={resolveAboutComponent} />
  </Route>
);
```

Notice how the root route gets wrapped with "authWrapper", there I check if user has JWT and dispatch to redux store the result.

**The question/problem:** How do I load different "child" component for authenticated and non-authenticated users when they enter IndexRoute ?

The above resolveIndexComponent just loads '/domains/home' which contains:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ authenticated: state.common.currentUser });


const App = (props) => {
  if (props.authenticated) {
    return (<Authenticated />);
  }
  return (<Unauthenticated />);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Could I skip this and load either `<Authenticated />` or `<Unauthenticated />` directly from react-router ? (based on either props or even what authWrapper returns)

Comment: i think you can write an `onEnter` function on a route and redirect the app to your desired component